# How can it be justified from utilitarianism that we must keep our promises?

Tags: ethics, utilitarianism

How can it be justified from utilitarianism that we must keep our promises?

I want to know if it can be justified from utilitarianism.

Comment: What are your own thoughts on the subject? Like keeping promises has some benefits in terms of how others are treating you, etc.

Comment: Welcome to SE. This is a good question. But it would be much improved if you could include some details, such as any ideas about it that you've come across in your reading and any thought you have yourself. For example, do you suspect that it can't be justified in utilitarian terms?

Comment: It's extremely hard to keep one's promises under the usual hypothetical imperatives utilitarinism context since your real world situations would change, same for the other parties' situations in the real saha world...

Answer (score 1):

Being able to rely on promises reduces the uncertainty of future events. This decreases the amount of resources that must be kept idle in preparation for an uncertain future (up to and including *all* my time and *all* my stuff as I go live alone in the woods and chase strangers away with threats of violence). This has a corresponding increase in the amount of resources available for utility-increasing activities such as consumption (including the consumption of my own time as leisure), investment (including the investment of my own labor time), and trade (in which I give you something that you get more utility out of than me and you give me something that I get more utility out of than you).